# How do I add multiple box-shadows to an element, but only apply a transition to one of them?

Tags: css

I know it's possible to add multiple box-shadows to an element using:

```
box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px #000000, 1px 1px 3px #FF0000;
```

but how do I apply a transition to only one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you'd have to explicitly list out *all* the `box-shadow`s, including the un-changed shadows, and animate *all* of them (despite the lack of change in some/most of them). An animation that changes nothing will, at least, *look* unanimated. Regardless of the behind-the-scenes `transition`.

Demonstrative CSS:

```
div {
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px #000000, 1px 1px 3px #FF0000;
    transition: box-shadow 1s linear;
}

div:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px #000000, 1px 1px 10px #FF0000;
    transition: box-shadow 1s linear;
}
```

[(simple) JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QGudL/).

Unfortunately there is, as yet (nor is there planned to be, so far as I'm aware), no method to name or identify individual `box-shadow`s.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! Very quick and helpful reply :]

And I can't really think of a scenario where'd you want to use more than 2 box-shadows (inset and outset) so I don't really see it being a problem.